# How to use grep to first digit of matching line

Tags: shell, command-line, grep

i would like to find *only* the first digit of a matching line. I know that the first digit can only be for `1 to 4`

For example this file

```
2 Eggs
1 Bacon
5 Bread
```

```
grep -i eggs | grep ^[14]** or **grep -i eggs | grep ^#
```

doesnt work....
but why not?

the expected result is the digit `2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `-o` option for grep to output *only* the matching text (not the whole line), and the regex `[1-4]` to match from 1 to 4 (as opposed to `[14]` which matches either 1 or 4)

```
grep -o '^[1-4]'
```

To wrap up your grep pipeline into a single command, you can use this if you have GNU grep:

```
grep -ioP '^[1-4](?=\s+eggs)'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `cut` command:

`grep -i eggs yourfile | cut -c1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`

```
awk '/eggs/ {print $1}' file
2
```

It will search for all lines with `eggs` then print first column `$1`